# Aggregate or not aggregate

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design

I have `User` model which is `aggregate`. I also plan to create `WorkingHours` object. It's like every `user` will have his own working hours per day. There will be also `graphical user interface` separated from `User` for `add/remove/update` hours etc. I am thinking that whether should i  put all operations into `UserRepository` related to `WorkingHours` or should i tread `WorkingHours model` as `aggregate` and create separated `WorkingHoursRepository` so then i could put `property` into `User` as `id` to `WorkingHours` object. Which option should i choose?

My thoughts are that to not make `WorkingHours` as aggregate because every set of working hours belong to specific `user` which makes it if i am thinking right dependent on `User` and cannot live without it. My only thought about to make it aggregate and create separate repository is due to have cleaner code means not to put all `CRUD` etc in same `repository` but i suppose it's should be not the thing to separate it therefore to me the only way is to `WorkingHours` as `value object` and not `aggregate` and use `UserRepository` for it.

Answer (score 0):

You design your Domain Model based on your business requirements and not on how it needs to be saved.

In this scenario,  if `Working Hours` can be only manipulated within the `User` domain and if you think `User` is the only aggregate required, then `Working Hours` should not be made aggregate. That said, it does not stop you save your data in a clean manner in your data store. Strategy to store your data also depends a lot on your type of data store.

For example, if you are using SQL and your data is stored in multiple tables then you can `Commit` or `Rollback` the entire transaction. How you implement it is not tied to DDD as long as you are adhering to the concept that the aggregates should only be updated via the root entity.

If you are using a No-SQL database like `Cosmos DB` you can choose to load or save the entire document. In that case, you would be only dealing with the `User` repository.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use sql. I was told only aggregates should have their own repository and eventually query. So then if WorkingHours require User because every User have their working hours means WorkingHours should be Value objects and be placed inside UserRepository (for modifying data) and UserQuery (reading data). As far as i understood you saying same. To me sometimes it is just not handy if things belogns strictly to aggregate have to be placed inside same Repository which makes it bigger ...

Comment: Not sure if you are using `C#`, but in the past, we have used `partial class` to divide the big classes into more `functional`  pieces. For example, you could create a `partial` `class` `UserRepository.WorkHours.cs` and add all logic pertaining to `WorkingHourse` there.